# How to open different url in single web view android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-activity, webview

How do I open different different URL stores in different different buttons. I'm just creating a separate activity that contains web view .

For example, one button contains links of Google. Another is containing links of Facebook, and another is Gmail.

Now I don't want to create separate activity for each click - I just want to create a activity that contains web view and when someone clicks the button they get inside this activity and the provided link will open with custom loading view

Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please some minimal reproducible example with code you have written and you are struggling with, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can send the url of the website to the webview activity using intent and receive them accordingly!on each button click add you

```
    button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent=new Intent(this, webview.class);
        intent.putExtra("URL","your url");   
        startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
 button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent=new Intent(this, webview.class);
        intent.putExtra("URL","your url2");   
        startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
```

on your weview activity recive these urls and fire your webview as follows

```
  String url=getIntent().getExtras().getString("URL");
```

Comment: Thank You very much sir.

Answer (score 1):

just create the method in the activity in which u have to show webView, which takes a string as a input and use this string in place of URL of webView,
call this function in the onClick of each button and pass the URL of desired website as parameter, do this for all the buttons